# Release application Google maps API v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I have create a new key store from android studio. The next step was to generate SHA1 fingerprint based on that key (keytool -v -keystore keystore -list
). Lastly in google api console i registered the allowed application (based on SSH1 and package name).

The problem is that when i export apk and choose build type release the google maps not working (empty grid). In contrary when i export the app and choose build type debug it works as it should. The keystore is the same in both ways (i am NOT using debug.keystore). Any ideas what i miss?

Comment: Did you create a clientID for your release keystore file? It sounds like you created one for your debug keystore, but not release.

Comment: Hello Andy, yes i have used keytool in order to get SSH1 hash and then i put it in google developer console in these format SSH1_HASH:package. My problem is that this API key works only if i export apk from android studio and choose build type debug.

Answer (score 0):

You have two `google_maps_api.xml` files in below folders

```
1.  app/src/debug/res/values

2. app/src/release/res/values
```

But only the debug one contains your API key probably.